# Virtual short condition contradicts the equation for an op amp output voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm trying to understand how to analyze basic op amp circuits. From what I have found, the output voltage of an op amp is equal to the following equation:

```
Vout = A(Vp-Vn) 
where A= gain, 
Vp = voltage at non-inverting terminal, 
Vn = voltage at inverting terminal
```

According to the virtual short condition for negative feedback op amps, I am told that:

```
Vp=Vn
```

By this condition, how is the output of the op amp not always 0?

Comment: This has been answered on here many, many times.

Answer (score 1):

The virtual short-circuit is not an actual short-circuit.

The concept of the virtual short-circuit derives from inverting the first equation:

$$V_{out} = A (V_p - V_n)$$

$$V_p - V_n = \frac{V_{out}}{A}$$

Given that \$V_{out}\$ is in the range of a few volts (when not saturated), and that \$A\$ is on the order of 10<sup>5</sup> to 10<sup>6</sup>, it means that \$V_p - V_n\$ is on the order of no more than a few tens of microvolts — for all practical purposes, and especially for the purpose of analyzing the closed-loop behavior of the circuit, they are "shorted" together.

Comment: Okay, I think its starting to make sense. Is it correct to say "Vp-Vn approaches 0"?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up a few concepts.

The gain A here is the open loop gain of the op-amp, not the gain of the whole circuit.

First of all, the gain A is very large, for an ideal op-amp, infinite.

Therefore, Vout/A will, for an ideal op-amp, be zero.

Thus, Vp-Vn will be zero. Which means, they have equal voltage, whatever voltage it is. So they have a virtual short circuit.

And the output voltage can be anything except infinite, because any output voltage Vout divided by infinite is zero.

In real life, A is just very large. Say 100000, or 1e5, or 100dB.

So if you have a non-ideal real-life practical op-amp circuit, with for example 5V output, the difference between inputs is 50 microvolts, which is practically 0.

Answer (score 0):

> *According to the virtual short condition for negative feedback op
> amps, I am told that: Vp=Vn. By this condition, how is the output of
> the op amp not always 0?*

This is an ideal op-amp and, for this type of ideal op-amp the open loop gain is infinite hence, it follows that the output is indeterminate i.e. \$\infty\times 0 = \text{indeterminate}\$.

That doesn't help you understand op-amps any better but, it does correct your presumption.